# How to ignore certain fields with Jackson's ObjectMapper.readerForUpdating

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, objectmapper

I'm using Jackson 2.7.0

I'm trying to ignore `encodingType` when updating an existing object with some new values:

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
om.readerForUpdating(message).readValue(messageSubset);
```

`message` contains a value for `encodingType`.
`messageSubset` (JSON-string) does not contain an entry (no key-value) for `encodingType`.

What I've tried:

- For the ObjectMapper:

  - `om.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_EMPTY);`
- On the message class:

  - `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)`
  - `@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "encodingType" })`
  - `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY)`
  - `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)`
- On the field and on the getters/setters:

  - `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY)`
  - `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)`
  - `@JsonIgnore`
  - `@JsonSerialize(include=JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)`

Non of the above work! Any help? 
I suppose this has something to do with readerForUpdating and/or the fact that one of them is being updated.

Comment: I've just tried your code with a dummy `Message` class where `encodingType` is a `String` and it works fine. No annotations needed. Could you post the code for class of `message` and an example JSON ?

Comment: I fixed the problem by configering the ObjectMapper like this:

`om.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY);`

`om.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);`

`om.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_IGNORED_PROPERTIES, false);`


And on the Message class for the correct properties:

`@JsonIgnore` on the setter


`@JsonProperty` on the getter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed the problem by configuring the ObjectMapper like this (not sure if these are all needed though):

`om.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY);`
`om.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);`
`om.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_IGNORED_PROPERTIES, false);`

And on the Message class for the properties needed:

`@JsonIgnore` on the setter (excludes it when parsing to the Java object)
`@JsonProperty` on the getter (includes it when parsing to the JSON object)